# Laravel Registration Testing with modified input field names

Tags: php, laravel

#### Environment

- Laravel Version: 6.1.0
- PHP Version: 7.3.10

#### Description:

I have a customized Laravel authentication, which includes different field names. My password field is Password with capital P.
I have the following assertion:

```
$this->assertFalse(session()->hasOldInput('Password'));
```

The following dump shows the inputted password.

```
dd(session()->getOldInput('Password');
```

It looks the validator does not know to omit the new password field from the return. 
I can do it in the controller with

```
... ->withInput($request->only(['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Email']))
```

But that does not work for the Validator.

I digged into these files:

vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException.php

But they have no mention of password. Any clue where is the validator filters the requests or how to add a custom filter to that?

Additionally, these are the rules in my controller:

```
return Validator::make($data, [
            'FirstName' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'LastName' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'Email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
            'Password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
```

If I run my test on a clean install or laravel with field name as 'password' it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your custom field name to the `$dontFlash` array in `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`

```
protected $dontFlash = [
    'Password',
    'Password_confirmation',
];
```

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Exceptions/Handler.php

Comment: That was what I was looking for, great!
How did you know this? Is there a mention in the documentation anywhere?
I checked Error Handling, but nothing mentions it there: https://laravel.com/docs/master/errors

Comment: @Mcload It's not in the docs, but the docs do point us to the `Handler.php`.